# How to declare extern("C") const function?

Tags: d

I'd like to write D bindings. For the life of the class `A` its `someStruct *` member variable will never change, so I guess it is natural to declare it as `immutable`. But then its constructor wouldn't compile unless I manage somehow to declare the `APICall` function's return value as `const`. How to do that?

```
struct someStruct;

const someStruct* APICall();

class A
{
    this()
    {
        this.ptr = myfunc();
    }
    private:
    immutable someStruct* ptr;
}
```

Error: `function app.APICall without 'this' cannot be const`

Comment: In the current form it's the function itself that's const. Here it's a NOOP but when the function is member of _class_ or a _struct_ it means that a call to the function does not modify the _struct_ or the _class_ state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use parenthesis around the return value:

```
const(someStruct*) APICall();
```

or if it never changes, `immutable` is better. (`const` is mostly useful on function parameters rather than return values)

const or immutable without parenthesis before or after a function declaration applies to the `this` parameter, which is why the error says what it says: you are trying to apply it to a `this` which isn't there.

But, before doing this, make sure it is *actually* immutable - that the pointer never changes AND that the data it points to never changes either. If there's any mutability through the pointer, you should just make it mutable.